# Nodejs update req in a function does not effect

Tags: node.js

I have two functions. I am doing same process in both functions. function1 updates the req as i want and i can use the array in other functions.
In function2, array is adding to req, but when i try to use array in other functions, it is disappering. How can i do it in function2. Thanks.

function1:

```
router.post('/sign_in-sign_in', function(req, res, next) {
var v_sql_application_set=[{$match:{user_id:req.session.user__info.user_id }},{$project:{dim_id:1,application_set:1}}];
        querySelect( v_sql_application_set,"t_application_set","aggregate").then(function (application_set_result){
            req.session.Qxresult__t_application_set = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < application_set_result.length; i++) { 
                req.session.Qxresult__t_application_set.push({application_set:application_set_result[i].application_set});
            }
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log("Error in f_refresh_session_vectors :ErrorNo1 "+JSON.stringify(error));
            v_cmessage="Unexpected Error. Try Again. (Error in f_refresh_session_vectors :ErrorNo1) "+JSON.stringify(error);
            res.render('error',{user_info:req.session.user__info});
        });
});
```

Function2:

```
function fx_refresh_session_vectors(req)
{
var v_sql_application_set=[{$match:{user_id:req.session.user__info.user_id }},{$project:{dim_id:1,application_set:1}}];
        querySelect( v_sql_application_set,"t_application_set","aggregate").then(function (application_set_result){
            req.session.Qxresult__t_application_set = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < application_set_result.length; i++) { 
                req.session.Qxresult__t_application_set.push({application_set:application_set_result[i].application_set});
            }
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log("Error in f_refresh_session_vectors :ErrorNo1 "+JSON.stringify(error));
            v_cmessage="Unexpected Error. Try Again. (Error in f_refresh_session_vectors :ErrorNo1) "+JSON.stringify(error);
            res.render('error',{user_info:req.session.user__info});
        });
}
```

Comment: Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for learn how to do a good question, and tab your code, with Ctrl + K !

Comment: Are you using the second function during the same request handler?

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking these? May I also suggest that you have some bugs in this code, including the `catch` handler on function2. `res` is not defined in the context as far as the example shows.

Comment: The answer for Andrzej Gorgon: Yes

Comment: The answer for ginman:    f_refresh_session_vectors(req).then(function (req){
     // do nothing
    console.log("DGGLOGmain_after_normal:"+JSON.stringify(req.session));
     
    }).catch(error=>{
     console.log("Error in my_reports_application_based:ErrorNo1 "+JSON.stringify(error));
     v_cmessage="Unexpected Error. Try Again. (Error in my_reports_application_based:ErrorNo1) "+JSON.stringify(error);
     res.render('error', {cmessage:v_cmessage,user_info:req.session.user__info});
    });